# Apply a function to a group to make changes to data

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

In my sample data below, I want to groupby column `cola` and within each group: 1) find the first row in column `colb` with a value `g`, 2) make all rows before that row to be empty (for `colb`).

note: originally i was looking for the value `2`, but i realize i actually want a string so i'm changing it to `g`

Sample Data:

```
cola, colb
a, s
a, g
a, a
b, s
b, d
b, g
```

End goal:

```
cola, colb
a, 
a, g
a, a
b, 
b, 
b, g
```

I am thinking of using `groupby.apply()` but based on examples don't have it quite down. Am thinking of something like

```
def myfunc(group):
    first2row = df[df['colb'] == 'g'].index[0]
    df.loc[0:first2row, ['colb']] = ''

df.groupby('cola').apply(myfunc)
```

Any thoughts or suggestions? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `df` in your function use the parameter passed with `head(1)` i.e

```
def x(y):
    if y[y == '2'].any():
        j = y[y == '2'].head(1).index[0]
        y.loc[0:j-1] = ''
    return y

df['k'] = df.groupby('cola')['colb'].apply(x)
```

Output :

```
Case 1 :
 cola colb  k
0    a    0   
1    a    2  2
2    a    2  2
3    b    0  0
4    b    1  1
5    b    1  1

Case 2 :
  cola colb  k
0    a    0   
1    a    2  2
2    a    2  2
3    b    0   
4    b    1   
5    b    2  2
```

Comment: thanks! still curious about Wen's use of transform, but this definitely works and helps me understand `.apply`

Answer (score 1):

Or you try `transform`

```
df['row']=df.groupby('cola')[' colb'].transform('idxmax')
df.loc[df.index<df.row,' colb']=''
df.drop('row',1)
Out[410]: 
  cola  colb
0    a      
1    a     2
2    a     2
3    b      
4    b      
5    b     2
```

Updated 2

Data Input

```
 cola colb
    a   1
    a   2
    a   3
    b   1
    b   1
    b   2
    b   3

df['row']=df.groupby('cola')[' colb'].transform(lambda x : x[x<=2].idxmax())

df.loc[df.index<df.row,' colb']=''
df.drop('row',1)

Out[548]: 
  cola  colb
0    a      
1    a     2
2    a     3
3    b      
4    b      
5    b     2
6    b     3
```

Update 3

```
df['row']=df.groupby('cola',as_index=False)[' colb'].transform(lambda x : (x[x==' g']).index.values[0])
df.loc[df.index<df.row,' colb']=''
df.drop('row',1)
Out[609]: 
  cola  colb
0    a      
1    a     g
2    a     a
3    b      
4    b      
5    b     g
```

Comment: Transform is really nice but OP asked of apply na. If he has multiple conditions then? If he wants to equate `==` for two numbers or more this wont work.

Comment: thanks for the alternate idea. would this still work if there were some values of `3` in `colb` and i still wanted to remove values in rows prior the the first occurance of `2`?

Comment: Thanks! OK i see now that this sample data wasn't exactly what i wanted, but would this still work if `2` was a string?. Sorry... i realize i should have specified that initially. regardless thanks for showing me the transform function

Comment: @As3adTintin I am not quit sure about whether it is work for string or not , maybe you can update the dput in your question :) and why not `astype(int)` change to int

Comment: @As3adTintin Updated.again .